# Can we run python progam in cgi?

Tags: cgi

The HTML form that I makes use of uses browse option and the file format uploaded  is like this(/home/anu/anu.py). Now  since in the form action the processing takes place in the server side. can we use CGI for taking the filename as input and process the text using the python program in the hard disk and display the output on the web page.
Is there any code available?
can we run python program in the hard disk using CGI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run Python programs with CGI. The [`cgi`](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html) standard module will help.

Answer (score 1):

In Apache you can configure additional extensions to be treated as cgi.
The directory that contains the CGI will have to have these option included 

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI 
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py